# How to load a serialized file back to an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, load, jlist, serializable

ive looked at a few problems on this matter already but couldnt resolve my issue.

As you can see below, i save all the objects in my `Patient ArrayList`(`pList` - which is private at the top of the class) into the "Patient.ser" file through serialization. As far as i can tell this is working with no problems. "`patSizeAtSave`" is a private variable which i am using to mark as a bound to work with when loading the file(see below)

the "`patModel`" is the `DefaultListModel` i use for the `JLists` in my `GUI` so i try to populate those lists with what has been added back to the `Patient ArrayList(pList)`

**MY PROBLEM**: When i hit the load button on the `GUI` it calls the `loadPatientList()` method below, but nothing is being put into my JLists so i can't tell if it works at all.

Any idea's on how to fix this?

```
private void savePatientList() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try
    {
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Patient.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
    for(Patient p: pList)
    {
        os.writeObject(p);
    }
    fs.close();
    os.close();
    patSizeAtSave = pList.size();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTabPane, "Save Complete!", "Notification", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

}
private void loadPatientList()
{
    FileInputStream fs;
    ObjectInputStream is;
    try
    {
    fs = new FileInputStream("Patient.ser");
    is = new ObjectInputStream(fs);

    for(int i = 0; i < patSizeAtSave; i++)
    {
        Patient p = (Patient) is.readObject();
        pList.add(p);
        patModel.addElement(p.getPNo() + ": " + p.getPName());
    }
    jListPatient.setModel(patModel);
    jListPatient2.setModel(patModel);
    fs.close();
    is.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to load you patients list in the same JVM (without exiting the JVM) after saving it ? 
Because if you exit your JVM before reloading you patients list, your patSizeAtSave will be reset to 0 (since it is not saved to any file/persitent storage) but only in memory. When you will call loadPatientList in a new JVM, your for loop will not load any patient since patSizeAtSave is 0.

You should rather save the whole list pList (assuming you use a Serializable implementation of List, sucha as ArrayList / LinkedList), like this :

```
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Patient.ser");
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
os.writeObject(pList);
```

And load it back with :

```
pList = (List<Patient>) is.readObject();
for(Patient p: pList)
{
    patModel.addElement(p.getPNo() + ": " + p.getPName());
}
```

This way, the list size will also be saved in you serialized file.

Regards

Comment: Thanks you so much man! Thats working with no problems now!

That was a stupid error with the private variable patSaveAtSize, i forgot it was gone...

However i did try it by saving and loading the entire arraylist as an object before, but what i didnt do is include "<Patient>" in the ArrayList casting back part of the code. thanks very much once again.

Comment: Happy I could help. Could you please vote and mark your question as answered. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Cool Man thats done, im new to this site so ill make sure to remember to wrap it up in future